# How to explain the asymmetry of vanilla Volga?

Tags: black-scholes, greeks, vanna-volga

[image]

I've plotted the charts of Volga of Vanilla Call/Put using finite difference method, and found they are the same, and an asymmetrical shape of observed for both. Any intuitive way to explain the behaviour, or why ITM call/OTM put has higher Volga?

Comment: These charts look correct. http://www.ericbenhamou.net/documents/Encyclo/volga.pdf The Vega of a Put and a Call are the same (due to put call parity), so the volga (the derivative of vega with respect to $\sigma$) of Put and Call are also the same. Also, it is true that it goes to zero when $S=K$. But your main question, about the asymmetric peaks, I don't know the  answer.

Answer (score 3):

The shape you observe is really only due to spot being higher for ITM calls & OTM puts.

The plots are definitely correct. You can quickly check by using standard [closed form volga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)#Formulas_for_European_option_Greeks), which is $$vega*\frac{d1*d2}{\sigma}$$.

[image]

Changing risk free rate and dividends just shifts the whole graph slightly left or right respectively.

Volga is $$vega*\frac{d1*d2}{\sigma}$$ hence $$ S * e^{-d*t}*n(d1) * \sqrt \tau*\frac{d1*d2}{\sigma}$$ with $d_1= \frac{\ln S- \ln K +(r-d+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)\tau }{\sigma \sqrt{\tau}}$ and $d_2= d_1 - \sigma \sqrt{\tau}$.

As $n(d1)>0$ whenever $\sigma \sqrt{\tau}>0$, it can only be explained with two things, spot $S>0$, or the term $\frac{d1*d2}{\sigma}$. The latter is a bit tricky, and could be similar to what happens with [delta](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/65960/54838) at a first glance.
The $d1*d2$ part may look daunting, but PCs allow you to deal with this quickly. The below uses [Julia](https://julialang.org/).

```
function d1d2Vol(S,K,t,rf,d,σ) d1 = ( log(S/K) + (rf - d + 1/2*σ^2)*t ) / (σ*sqrt(t))
  d2 = d1 - σ*sqrt(t)
  vega_c = S * exp(-d*t)*n(d1) * sqrt(t)*0.01
  volga = vega_c*((d1*d2)/σ)
  return d1*d2/σ, vega_c, volga
end

spotRange = 10:10:300
K         = 150
rf        = 0 
d         = 0
σ         = 0.2
t         =1
df = DataFrame(d1d2Vol.(spotRange,K,t,rf,d,σ))
rename!(df,[:d1d2v,:vega,:volga] )
```

[image]

This looks like $(d1*d2)/σ$ actually has the opposite effect of what is observed. Plotting it shows this indeed.

```
plot(spotRange,[df.d1d2v], label= L"\frac{d1*d2}{\sigma}",size=(800,650), legendfontsize=20, xlabel = "Spot", ylabel= L"\frac{d1*d2}{\sigma}")
```

[image]

So the only thing left to explain the difference (that also must offset the opposite effect of $(d1*d2)/σ$) is the spot price. If you take a closer look at Black Scholes, this also makes intuitive sense. The standard formula as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance)#Formulas_for_European_option_Greeks) is providing a result in currency.

```
function BSM(S,K,t,rf,d,σ)
  d1 = ( log(S/K) + (rf - d + 1/2*σ^2)*t ) / (σ*sqrt(t))
  d2 = d1 - σ*sqrt(t)
  c  = exp(-d*t)S*N(d1) - exp(-rf*t)*K*N(d2)
  vega = S * exp(-d*t)*n(d1) * sqrt(t)*0.01 
  volga = vega*((d1*d2)/σ)
  return c, vega, volga
end
```

Now, pricing two identical options with $S=90$, $K=100$, $t=1$ year, zero rates and dividends and the only difference being vol of $\sigma=0.2$ and $\sigma=0.21$ you can see how adding vega is close to the new value of the option after increasing vol.

[image]

However, that is dependent on the actual value of spot (and strike). Assume you look at [Berkshire](https://www.google.com/search?q=berkshire+price&rlz=1C1GCEA_enGB934GB934&oq=berkshire+price&aqs=chrome..69i57j46i175i199j0l4j46i175i199j69i60.3612j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) which is currently around USD 421,350.

[image]

Vega still works, but the value is vastly different to before. "Issue" here is that the BS price is in cash, not percent of underlying. If you transform it into a comparable percentage price, you see that both options ae priced the same way (which they should as it is the same inputs and same moneyness).

[image]

You can easily transform one volga into the other by dividing by spot of the volga, and multiple by other spot value.

[image]

A final sanity check is to exclude S in the volga formula and plot the same value again. Indeed, as the size of $(d1*d2)/σ$ suggests, the highest point is now actually on the left hand side.

[image]